# Create Static Directed Graph in Julia

Tags: julia, lightgraphs

How can I create a Static Directed Graph from an array of tuples in Julia without having to create a Simple Directed Graph first. An example edge list I have is `[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]`. The documentation of StaticGraphs.jl is limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way to do this but it requires you to have the edges *and their reverses* already sorted into two vectors. Assume you have a directed path graph 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4:

```
fwd = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]  # these are your forward edges, sorted
rev = [(2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3)]  # these are the reverse of the forward edges, sorted
# also, sort(reverse.(fwd)) will do this easily.

g = StaticDiGraph(4, fwd, rev)  # number of vertices is the first argument
```

testing:

```
julia> h = StaticDiGraph(path_digraph(4))
{4, 3} directed simple static {UInt8, UInt8} graph

julia> g == h
true
```

Comment: Also, for future reference, posting in the Julia discourse or in the `#graphs` channel in the Julia slack will likely get you more timely answers.